# How do Catmull-Rom and Hermite splines relate?

Tags: spline, catmull-rom-curve, hermite

I'm a little confused as to how they relate. From my class, my professor asked how to fit C1 continuous piecewise Hermite curves to x amount of points with automatically computed tangents. Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 14):

**Hermite** spline is a method of **representation** of cubic curve with two endpoints and two tangent vectors at these endpoints.
Note that there are many approaches to represent the same curve- power basis (at^3+bt^2+ct+d), Bernstein polynomials (for Bezier curves) and so on.

**Catmull-Rom** spline is a method of **construction** of a cubic curve (C1 continuous, if some pieces used). Every Catmull-Rom segment **is** a Hermite spline.  If we want to represent a Catmull-Rom spline for the P1-P2 segment of the (P0,P1,P2,P3) point sequence as a Hermite one, we just use P1 and P2 as endpoints, and V1 and V2 as tangent vectors, where

```
V1 = tau * (P2-P0) 
V2 = tau * (P3-P1)
```

([good article here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/graphics/asst5/catmullRom.pdf))
and tau is parameter of tension (rigidness)

Comment: Looks to me like the correct answer, and as such should be marked as answer!
Although you might have mentioned more detailed (like in bold letters maybe), that a Catmull-Rom spline actually **is** a Hermite spline.